# jQuery execute function after complete

Tags: jquery

This is probably very basic but I can not seem to find a clear answer to my case.

I would like to know how to ensure that one function is executed and complete before the rest of the work flow can continue

in my script below the alerts fire as "1", "3", "2" where I would like getsS3policy(file) to be complete before the script steps into up.settings.multipart_params

```
preinit: {

            UploadFile: function (up, file) {
                getS3Policy(file);
                alert("3");
                    up.settings.multipart_params = {
                        key: path,
                        filename: file.name,
                        AWSAccessKeyId: 'AKIAJIRIA6XD4V5MFWCA',
                        acl: 'private',
                        policy: policy,
                        signature: signature,
                        success_action_status: '201'
                    }

            }
        },

    });
    function getS3Policy(file) {
        alert("1");
        data = { 'alc': 'private', 'bucket': 'PhotojimaDev', 'key': path, 'file': file.name };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/desktopmodules/uploader/API/upload/getPolicy',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response) {
                    policy = response.policy;
                    signature = response.signature;
                    alert("2");
                }
                else {
                    return "Error";
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a callback of jQuery ajax. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: how might I do a callback to the next step in my script?

Answer (score 1):

The `success` function of your ajax call is the callback. That's what runs once the data is received if you put your `up.settings.multipart_params` in that callback, it will only run once the data is received.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/desktopmodules/uploader/API/upload/getPolicy',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response) {
                policy = response.policy;
                signature = response.signature;
                alert("2");
                up.settings.multipart_params = {
                    key: path,
                    filename: file.name,
                    AWSAccessKeyId: 'AKIAJIRIA6XD4V5MFWCA',
                    acl: 'private',
                    policy: policy,
                    signature: signature,
                    success_action_status: '201'
                }
            }
            else {
                return "Error";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that approach before but for some reason when I do it that way amazon s3 returns an error saying that "key" can not be found in the POST request. Looking at the request, the only values that make it into the request are 'name" and "filename". I figured the scope of the code was out so I decided to re-write it such as how it is found in my question.